# Парсинг модального окна

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, парсер

Появилась необходимость в парсинге данных в модальном окне: при клике на пункт меню открывается окно, затем в него подгружаются данные, адрес страницы при этом не меняется. При попытке проделать данное действие с помощью SimpleBrowser код окна не сохраняется в самом браузере. Как можно спарсить необходимые мне данные?

Comment: `Как можно спарсить необходимые мне данные` - ну, наверно получить данные напрямую с источника?

Comment: Попробуйте AngleSharp с конфигурацией `.WithJavaScript()`. Примеры можно найти и на [ru so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anglesharp)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ проследить последовательность вызовов и проделать подобное?

Comment: @AK спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: @mtrfnv Именно так. Обычно это всего 1 POST запрос на определенный адрес, который выдает результат в виде JSON/XML.

Comment: Надо бы изменить заголовок вопроса на "Парсинг вебсайта" или что-то такое, ну никак не парсинг окна. Окно и в Африке окно, его не нужно парсить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ пошел этим путем. все получилось